# Chaining two columns into one string in Mysql

Tags: php, string, if-statement, echo

I am trying to code an emailer that emails customers of a company.

What happens is when the field businessname is blank, the salutation and the second name should be used in its place instead.

The problem I am having is I dont think I am using the correct syntax to join the two strings, it is supposed to output something like 'Mr Jones' , but I am just getting a syntax error so I think it is probably my shoddy coding, I have not been doing php very long so i'm not very good.

```
<?php
if ($businessname == '')
{
    $name = $row->salutation & $row->surname;
}
else 
{
    $name = $row->businessname;
}    

echo $name;
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't really get a syntax error with the above code, although it won't do what you expect it to. You should probably have a good read of the [manual section on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Regardless, the string concatenation operator in PHP is `.` - so the syntax for what you want to do is:

```
if ($businessname == '') {
  $name = $row->salutation.$row->surname;
} else {
  $name = $row->businessname;
}
echo $name;
```

You can do this more simply using a [ternary](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) expression:

```
$name = ($businessname == '') ? $row->salutation.$row->surname : $row->businessname;
echo $name;
```

If you need to insert a space between the variables, you would just do this:

```
$row->salutation.' '.$row->surname
```

FYI, what your original code did was a [bitwise](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) AND between the two variables.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, the top one works but ends up with MrJones instead of Mr Jones (no space), do I need to use . . for a space ?

Comment: See the last little code section of my answer. You would need to concatenate three strings - the first string, then a string containing a space (`' '`), then the last string.

Comment: Ahh yes, I just worked it out before I came here after trying different options, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate strings you have to use '.'

```
$m1 = 'Hello';
$m2 = 'World';
$test = $m1.' '.$m2;
```

You should look at that for more examples : 
http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-string-concatenation.html